# se pueden colocar html en el placeholder con boostrap u otro metodo?

Tags: css3, bootstrap, textarea

necesito hacer un placeholder de un textarea como se muestra en la imagen, con un h1 y un h3 donde coloco un enlace. estuve viendo la documentacion de boostrap pero no encuentro como lograrlo. Si encontre que se puede usar en los toolstips pero nada sobre lo que estoy necesitando. Gracias por el aporte.

**texto en negrita**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar aquello que hayas intentado al momento?

Comment: no tengo problema en mostrar el texto en el placeholder, sino que necesito editar dos lineas de texto que figuran en el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo claro que con un textarea vayas a poder anidar otras etiquetas como h1, ya que un textarea tiene un mismo estilo de fuente para todo su contenido. Lo que sí puedes hacer es tener un DIV con contenido editable y estilos que hagan que parezca un textarea

Luego es tan fácil como hacer que al empezar a escribir se borre el contenido inicial del div y ya tendrías tu "placeholder" listo.
El código para el div es

`<div contenteditable="true" class="w-100 pt-5"><h1>Happy to see you!</h1>It's your workspace blablabla <a href="asd">Esto es un enlace</a></div>`
(Las clases son de bootstrap)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como ya dijo que encontró maneras de poner placeholders pero no con estilo, me pareció correcto enseñarle esta manera de hacerlo, @BetaM

Comment: es exactamente lo que estaba necesitando! no sabia que un div podia transformarse en textarea. pruebo y te cuento como me fue. mil gracias!

Comment: tenia 2 problemas, el primero es que el enlace no se comporta como tal.... no redirigia a ningun lado y lo solucione asignandole a la etiqueta <a> texteditable="false" y se soluciono.
Lo otro es si se puede hacer que cuando uno comienza a escribir se borre el texto original? ya seria usando js o no?

Comment: Al div le puedes metes una función en el 'onkeyup' que borre el contenido si es la primera vez que detecta una pulsación :) Si te ha ayudado marca como respuesta por favor :)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte! soluciono mi problema